# Browser resets hash routes on post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, fetch-api

I use the react `HashRouter` from `react-router-dom`

```
import {HashRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
<HashRouter>
  <div className="container">
    <NavBar/>
    <Route path="/p1" component={C1}/>
    <Route path="/p2" component={C2}/>
    <Route path="/p3" component={C3}/>
  </div>
</HashRouter>
```

And Redux store

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App/>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('content')
```

On submitting a post request via redux function the hashes in the browser are removed and I come back to `/`.

```
export const postEntitiy= entitiy=> (dispatch, getState) => {

  return fetch('/entity/save/', {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(product)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(saveEntityOk(json)));
};
```

The desired behaviour would be no redirect here. The serverside just returns normal json.

Comment: So you mean you make a submit at `/p1` and then you end in `/`?

Comment: Yes if the URL ist ```index.html#/pX``` any submit of a post request will bring me to ```#/```

Comment: You probably should make it clear in your question

Comment: How is your form rendered? You should show the relevant code

Comment: Ill do later the day. But essentially its just a React create Component. I checked it with a minimal page component that just has a div and a button which sends an arbitrary json object. The routes always reset. It does not reset when using get requests to send stuff to the server.